# How to explain swap two integers without using a third variable

Tags: java

I found the following code to swap two integers without a third variable:

```
a=b+(b=a)*0
```

Can anyone explain it in details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: This is just a very ugly way of swapping values. Just use a third variable.

Comment: just classic school task "swap two vars without three"

Comment: This would be a much better question if you break it down a bit to understand the individual parts and ask about the specific part you don't understand. Although playing around with it a bit should make what's going on there really obvious really quickly. I mean, should we explain what `+`, `=` or `*` does? That `b+0 = b`? Order of evaluation? That `=` returns a value? This just seems too broad.

Comment: I didn't say it's too easy, I said it's too broad (although if you don't understand the individual operations here, a textbook might be a better place to learn this than [so]).

Comment: @Dukeling how do you know i didn't check the book or other resources? I asked "explain this line of code in details", you feel its broad but there are 4 answers accurately got my point.

Comment: I don't see how this question is unclear. OP sees a piece of code (s)he doesn't understand and wants it explained. If asking a question about complicated code isn't within the scope of this site, what is?

Comment: @corsiKa There are ways to frame questions properly. Dumping code isn't one of them. Dukeling isn't asking for much. What part of that expression is confusing? So answers can concentrate on those.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Would you expect any change in the question to actually change an answer? A good answer would be explaining the entire statement anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a variable, you also return that variable as the result.

```
a=b+(b=a)*0
```

We're assigning `a` some value. What is this value? Well, it's `b + (some quantity) * 0`. Anything times 0 is 0, so we know that this point `a = b`.

In the mean time, in the middle there, we're assigning `b = a`. These are the swaps that count. And because we put the `b` on the stack before the `(b=a)` that b is saved.

So in short it does use a temporary variable, if you think about it. It pushes `b` on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze it bit by bit.

- Start with `(b=a)`, is the first operation performed due to the parenthesis, and assigns `b` with `a`'s value, and returns the assigned value (`a`)
- That expression (resulting in `a`) is multiplied by `0` (next priority operation)
- It is then added to `b` inline (so `a = [old reference to b] + 0`)
- And there you have it

Comment: *Start with (b=a), is the first operation performed due to the parenthesis, and assigns b with a's value* if that would have been the case, wouldn't the value of a be equal to a again?

Comment: @nullpointer No because the value of `b` is pushed onto the stack before the assignment.

Comment: @nullpointer there's a "trick". The expression is still evaluated left to right. So the first occurrence of `b` is actually still holding `b`'s original value when evaluated. You can actually test that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this could go as a community post as well:

```
a=b+(b=a)*0

=> a = b + 0 // multiplication with 0, so 'a' would be assigned the value of 'b'

=> a = b + (b=a) * 0 // basically assign existing value of a to b here
```

The crux is using the existing values since if the expression would be split into multiple statements, chances are using their updated values in the evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this step by step, using some values as example

a = 10

b = 20

a = b + (b = a) * 0

So "dereferenced" we got the following:

a = 20 + (b = 10) * 0

So we assign 10 to b "on the fly" and assign the sum of 20 + 10 * 0 to a. 10 * 0 is calculated first, so we end up with

a = 20 + 0

Without the * 0, a would contain the sum of a and b before the swap of the values.